# multiple Access queries using same criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, criteria

New to this...

I have a table `QAQC_Studies` that includes titles, dates, and subject matter
I have another table `QAQC_Publications` that includes citation information for multiple publications resulting from a single study in the first table.

Every 3 months I need to create a report to QC studies added by coworkers so I run the following query (with some additional attributes removed for brevity). The where clause is a list of study `ID`s they provide me (often 15-20 different studies).

```
SELECT QAQC_Studies.StudiesID, 
   QAQC_Studies.NSL, 
   QAQC_Studies.StudyTitle, 
   QAQC_Studies.Abstract, 
   QAQC_Studies.StudyStatus

FROM QAQC_Studies
WHERE [QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID]=26806 or 26845
```

I'd like to add to that report a list of the publications associated with each study.

How do I write the Where clause in the second query to reference those studies indicated in the first query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery. Something like:

```
SELECT [QAQC_Publications].[QAQC_Field]
FROM [QAQC_Publications]
WHERE [QAQC_Publications].[StudiesID] --or whichever field the two tables 
                                      --share for publication/study connection
IN (SELECT QAQC_Studies.StudiesID 
FROM QAQC_Studies
WHERE [QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID]=26806 or 26845)
```

Comment: `WHERE [QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID]=26806 or 26845` is not valid. I think you mean `WHERE [QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID] in (26806, 26845)`

Comment: Also the `[QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID]` in the where clause of the subquery is the same `[QAQC_Studies].[StudiesID]` being returned. Why not skip that step and just use `IN` at the parent level?

Comment: Both where clauses worked fine. Thanks for the help!